# Example on Correspondences

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of correspondences F: X $\rightarrow$ Y, G: Y $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^s$ such that F and G are closed, but (G o F) is not, if any, where $ \varnothing \neq X \subset\mathbb{R}^m,  \varnothing \neq Y \subset\mathbb{R}^n $.

I need help with this question. This is all the information given. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks.